# Hiding data on each frame of an H.264 video

Tags: video, encoding, h.264, steganography

I have found some steganography techniques that allow hiding data on the *encoded* frames of an H.264 video ([ref](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326914386_H264AVC_Video_Steganography_Techniques_An_Overview)). However, I'd like to know if it's possible to somehow add the hidden data to each frame *before encoding* so this data can be retrieved after the video is decoded.

I know that the H.264 compression is lossy, so some of the original image data can be lost during the encoding process, but since the compression algo has a different effect on different regions of a frame, I wonder if the data could be hidden in areas that are less susceptible of being distorted.

Answer (score 0):

H.264 images are divided into 16x16 *macroblocks* before coding. If you inserted small luma (brightness) distortions into the interior of each macroblock you might be able to extract them from the decoded macroblocks. For example, let's say this is a scan line across three macroblocks for a total of 48 pixels. `x` pixels are the original images, and `#` are your distortions, for example.

```
                               #
                              #xx#
              #              #x  xxx
     x     xxxxx        # xx#xx   # xx x#x   ##
      xxxxxx#  #xxx    xxxx#             #x##xxxxxxx
        #  #    # xxxxx#                  #xx  ##
         #
     111111111111111122222222222222223333333333333333
```

Some things to keep in mind.

1. Avoid distortions at the edges of macroblocks, because they're more likely to show up as blockiness.
2. Avoid high-frequency distortions because the perceptual coding of H.264 sometimes attenuates them.
3. Keep the same distortion (hidden signal) for a few frames and then move to another one.
4. Use forward error correction code and lots of redundancy on your hidden bitstream. On extraction you are looking for a bent needle in a haystack.

I've never done this, so I'm speculating a bit. This is a [moving-pictures adaptation of JPEG steganograpy](https://alpinesecurity.com/blog/3-steps-to-hide-data-in-an-image-using-steganography/).